# How to get message shares?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I try to get shares object from messages sent between two users.

According to Facebook documentation I should use the method  **/{message-id}/shares**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/message/shares

But when I tried this with an user with **read_mailbox** permission I get the following error :

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api", 
        "type": "GraphMethodException", 
        "code": 100
    }
}
```

I use message's id retrieved with request **/me/inbox**

I am missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following format `/m_mid.$cAAGZr4WGacdkQBX_21eDtC3iV6w9/shares`